# Logistic sample and case numbers

Tags: logistic, sample-size, unbalanced-classes

I have some questions about binary logistic regression.
For my research, I am planning to use 12 predictors, and my sample consists of 129 cases. 
However, I know of a 1 to 10 rule.

Additionally, my DV is divided into 2 groups (it is a binary variable). It has an unbalanced distribution, and one group has less than 30 cases (`A` group: 104; `B` group: 25).

In this situation, can I run logistic regression?

Comment: Don't you mean DV - dependent variable?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/does-an-unbalanced-sample-matter-when-doing-logistic-regression  for the question about unbalanced samples

Answer (score 2):

That rule of thumb uses the number of cases in the minority group, in this case 25 in B. So you have about 2 events per variable<sup>†</sup>: you can still use logistic regression, but your model is likely to grossly over-fit the sample data—use bootstrap validation or cross-validation to estimate the consequences (or use the heuristic shrinkage estimator described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97048/97063#97063)).

Collecting more data would be a very good idea. You might want to reflect that the 95% confidence interval for the overall proportion of B is roughly (0.13,0.26), so you can't hope to learn about the individual effects of each of those 12 predictors with much precision at all. If you really need to build a predictive model on this sample, carrying out data reduction on the predictors would be sensible—try to get the number down to about two or three. [Regularization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4272/) is an alternative way to improve predictive accuracy.

† It's in fact events per regression degree of freedom you need to consider; so each dummy variable for a categorical predictor, each polynomial or spline term, counts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can I ask you one more thing? In my model, depedent variable is divided into two groups(1': 25, 0': 104). According your comment, the rule of thumb is used the cases(n=25). so, I can't use 12 predictors. However, if I have weight variable(my data is derived from pannel data), then, can I use 12 predicotrs? when I conduct frequency analysis with weight variable, my sample size is over 20,000.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a weight variable? See the distinction between survey weights & frequency weights discussed [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/). For frequency weights you do in fact have a greater sample size.